# Can an OpenID provider use Kerberos or other "alternate" authentication mechanisms?

Tags: authentication, active-directory, ldap, openid, kerberos

We are in a complex authentication environment and need to support authenticating against a number of disparate sources in applications we are developing. Since we don't want to be duplicating authentication code all over the place, we are looking at wrapping the various authentication sources with a single OpenID provider, and then having the applications all depend on that service.

The sources we have to allow authenticating against are things like Active Directory Username/Password, Kerberos, generic LDAP, external OpenID providers, etc.

For example, in the Kerberos case, when the user hits the OpenID provider's authentication page, if (s)he can be authenticated with Kerberos, and has already given permission to the requesting app, the user would be transparently authenticated *as if a password was entered* and passed back to the requesting app.

So, the question is, **can we have create an OpenID provider that handles authenticating through all of these various methods**? Does the provider have to implement *how* it authenticates the users in a specific way?

Comment: This is an interesting use-case. How does your team plan to manage the case where an authentication identity exists in multiple backends?

Comment: @TerryGardner, The user, in that case, will be presented with the option of authenticating with whichever method they wish. The OpenID provider could, in theory, connect identities from different sources, so the service can auto-authenticate if possible and fall back to a manual authentication method if needed. Eg. try Kerberos first and then fall back to an Active Directory username/password pair. From the requesting application's perspective, it's just an OpenID provider, which keeps things nice and simple, pushing all the auth complexity to the wrapping authentication service.

Comment: I see. In that case, I do not understand the question. Have you read and do you understand the [OpenID](http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html) specification?

Comment: @TerryGardner - Yes, the goal is to abstract a number of different authentication mechanisms that need to be supported, a number of which are single-sign-on. OpenID is _one_ way of making the abstraction more flexible, since it's a well supported standard and continues to be more and more popular. The question is "Can an OpenID provider use mechanisms _other than_ username/password to authenticate it's users when determining the identity of the user at the request of a 3rd party application?"

Comment: Great question, did you manage to find a working solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenID 2.0 specification do not specify how to authenticate users at the OpenID Provider there for it is vendor specific. So my answer is Yes, you can have an OpenID Provider that handles authentication through all those methods but you have to figure out how to, for example how to present the Kerberos tickets to the OpenID Provider is up to you to decide.

Comment: Is there anything in the OpenID authentication flow that would conflict with a Kerberos auth scheme between the user and the OpenID provider application?

Comment: No, How you authenticate the user at the OpenID Provider does not conflict with the OpenID Authentication protocol.